# Excel to copy matching cell row from tabs to a summary tab in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook and I need to find the NO values on ROW G (Row 7) and then copy the line that NO belongs to a new sheet (TAB) called summary, in my case it is listed as sheet 18.

I need to search on all sheets though from Sheet 1 to Sheet 17 in their G Rows for NO's.

I have a code I have found online and amend it to work with my criteria. But it does not seem to work as I would like it to it keeps coming up with errors.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nxtRow As Integer`enter code here`
'Determine if change was to Column G (7)
If Target.Column = 7 Then
'If Yes, Determine if cell = NO
If Target.Value = "NO" Then
'If Yes, find next empty row in Sheet 18
nxtRow = Sheets(18).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Copy changed row and paste into Sheet 18
Target.EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=Sheets(18).Range("A" & nxtRow)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.
Vasilis.

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/Greekcougar/media/screenshot9_zpslhtkkfue.jpg.html

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/Greekcougar/media/sub%20macro_zpsngyjtsj9.jpg.html

Comment: Mention the errors that you're getting.

Comment: The error I am getting
Run-time error '424'
Object required

Seems to be stopping on the first If

Comment: Any one else with more ideas about automation guys? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for the same. It has two sub procedures initiate and applyFilterAndCopy. In initiate you can specify the no. of sheets(**sheetCount** In below code I have mentioned as 2) you need to scan. While calling the second sub procedure inside first(**initiate**) you need to specify the column number and the text you are searching for as variables to the second sub procedure(**Call applyFilterAndCopy(i, 1, "No")** here I have mentioned as 1 i.e. 1st column and String to be searched as No in quotes). Please note the sheet names need to be in the format Sheet**** and summary sheet name as **Summary** case sensitive as mentioned in your description.

```
    Sub initiate()
     Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.Delete
     Dim i As Integer, sheetCount As Integer
     sheetCount = 2
     For i = 1 To sheetCount
      Call applyFilterAndCopy(i, 1, "No")
     Next i
    End Sub

    Sub applyFilterAndCopy(sheetNo As Integer, searchInColumn As Integer, textToSearch As String)
     Worksheets("Sheet" & sheetNo).AutoFilterMode = False
     Worksheets("Sheet" & sheetNo).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=searchInColumn, Criteria1:=textToSearch
     DR = Worksheets("Summary").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
     If IsEmpty(DR) = True Or DR = 1 Then
      Worksheets("Sheet" & sheetNo).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1")
     Else
      Worksheets("Sheet" & sheetNo).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Summary").Range("A" & DR + 1)
     End If
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Vba is not necessary for this. An easy way to do this is using a formula and filter. 
Add a column to the sheet that looks at the previous row and checks if no is there. Then filter this column and you can then just copy and paste to your summary tab.

Comment: Ok how will it copy automatically to the summary tab from the new "hidden row"?

Comment: My solution is intended as a manual solution not automatic one.

Comment: Thank you for that. 
A manual solution would have worked, however I wanted a summary page to be like a quick status report of what has NO.

In this case I do prefer an automatic solution than a manual.